# Converting a string into an logging object type

Tags: python, string, object, logging, type-conversion

I have a python logging object type for e.g: `<logging.Logger object at 0x00000000028AA0F0>` that is written in a text file and I am trying to convert that string into that same instance.

Note that this instance has already been created by the same program in the same computer. So how do you think I should turn that string into an object, so that I can reuse all its features.

Note: This is not a class object, it is a logging type object so I am guessing that makes a difference. I tried solving it by trying to convert it into a class object but I got an error that `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '<logging.Logger object at 0x00000000028AA0F0>`.

Comment: If I understand your question, you have the string `<logging.Logger object at 0x00000000028AA0F0>` and you want to convert the string to an actual logger instance. Is that correct?

Comment: @Mike67 Yes, that is correct!!!

Comment: Recovering the object is not possible. The string is just a representation of the object. The hex number is just a memory address where the object existed when you printed the string. When the process ended, the logger object was deleted.

Comment: @Mike67 Suppose I have the actual object. Is there a way to use that same object instance through different python modules by importing it without actually creating new instances? For e.g if I actually import the module where the instance was created originally, each time I import it a new instance gets created. But I want to use the same original instance, throughout all different modules, that was created the first time I ran that module.

Comment: yes - create a global variable that stores the logger object then use it throughout your script

Comment: @Mike67 But a global variable only exists in a module. So suppose I declare a global variable glob_var = logger i.e our object <logging.Logger object at 0x00000000028AA0F0> but each time I try to import that glob_var value in a different module the logger will trigger the statement which is initializing it which will create a new instance. That way I am not going to get the original object that was created the first time logger was initialized. How do I keep that record of the object such that it never changes no matter how many different modules import the global variable

Comment: You can create a singleton wrapper class that creates a single instance of the logger and always uses the same instance.

Comment: @Mike67 Ok I can extend this problem to convert my initialization of logger into a singleton class. Should I edit this question out or should I create a new question where I show my original initialization of logger? I do not know how to create singleton classes so are you willing to help? I would be very grateful if you can help me convert my initialization to a singleton class

Comment: Yes - please edit the question to show how you're using the logger code now and describe the goal. It should be simple enough to convert it to a singleton process.

Comment: @Mike67 I already made the question before you posted this comment. You can find it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64419489/converting-a-function-into-a-singleton-class-that-returns-one-instance. Please answer. Thank You